# Loss of internet connectivity when using Windows Phone 8 emulator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

When I run the Windows 8 phone emulator I lose internet on my PC. I am wireless network btw.

I am on Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: I found a lame workaround: launch emulator, reconnect to wireless network. Now the emulator will not have internet but PC will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a cabled network connection. I'm serious, we had everybody in the office switch to cables when we started using the WP8 SDK half a year ago.

Comment: did this problem happen for you?

Comment: Yes, of course. Happens pretty much all the time.

Comment: ok thanks for the input. I have +1 your answer but will not accept it as answer because there really should be a way to fix it without bringing cables into play. I mean this is 2012, most people are on the move when they code aswell.

Comment: The emulator creates a network bridge, that your PC then will use. Which works, most of the time, for most programs. If you have any network proxies or company firewalls, it's unlikely to work for you any time soon. Since it'll be a different solution for each person, it's hard to give a generic answer. It works for me one day, but not the next. Using a cable is the best general solution.

Comment: Actually I just went down and got me a ethernet cable, guess what. Windows 8 with all the hyper-v network adapters added, is not able to get internet connection at all! If nobody comes up with better answer in 24 hrs I will give accept yours.

Comment: Restarting your computer usually helps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19095/discussion-between-redhotscalability-and-claus-jorgensen)

Comment: I believe this may be caused by not all wireless cards(and/or drivers) supporting promiscuous mode